# Is this thread safe for two threads share on queue in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I got a `Queue` in my `Server` class:

```
public class Server{

    Queue<Input> inputQueue; 

    public void start() {
      inThread = new InThread(inputQueue);
      outThread = new OutThread(inputQueue);

      inThread.start();
      outThread.start();
    }
}
```

The `inThread` will responsible for fill in data in the inputQueue, and the `outThread` will responsible for take out data from the outputQueue. `InThread` and `OutThread` will execute concurrently. Will there a chance that the data will not thread safe? If so, I did some study, it have synchronized variable and synchronized method. Which one should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the queue is shared between threads so it is not thread safe without sunchronizing your read and write methods.

If you want a thread safe queue readymade then you may consider using ConcurrentLinkedQueue:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: I would use a Java 7 javadoc, if providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much of a need for hand-synchronization, although your existing approach is **not** threadsafe.

[java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)  can work for you. Its constructor allows one to pass in a collection, so you can do:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Input>blockingQueue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(128, false, inputQueue);
```

changing 128 as the capacity and the boolean as specifying whether queueing after blocks should be fair.

You can also use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). Its constructor is just:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Input> clq=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(inputQueue);
```

Comment: I would use a Java 7 javadoc, if providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ExecutorService which wraps a thread pool and a Queue and is thread safe/tested/is written for you.

You are right that some Queues require external synchronization but if you use a thread safe collection like ConcurrentLinkedQueue you don't need synchronized, though it won't hurt much if you do.

Answer (score 0):

To me Your question seems to be the case of  `standard producer consumer case with Wait and Notify`  .

Just google producer consumer example in java , you will get thousands of examples.Hope it helps.

Comment: I wouldn't use notify/wait unless you have to use Java 1.3 or older.  For Java 1.4+ I would use the concurrency library

Comment: Not a good idea for this, and also link-only answers are discouraged.